# Which is the better design approach - to return bool or to throw an exception?

Tags: c#, java, exception, handle

I'm wondering which approach is better. Let's say we have a method that, for example, sends a notification email.

```
void SendNotificaitonEmail();
```

So, I can edit my `SendNotificaitonEmail()` method so it now does the following:

```
bool SendNotificationEmail(out string errorMessage)
{
    try
    {
        // This is the code that handles the actual sending of the email.
        // ..
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

But isn't this wrong, in terms of design? For example, the `errorMessage` variable has nothing to do with the concept of `SendNotificationEmail()` method. Moreover, I should then add two new variables to all of my methods - a boolean one, stating the result of the method (true/false), and a string one, containing the error message, if one occurs.

The other way is to create my custom exceptions and handle them in the other methods that are invoking the first one.

```
public void SendNotificaitonEmail()
{
    try
    {
        // This is the code that handles the actual sending of the email.
        // ..

        if (somethingIsWrong == true)
        {
            throw new MyCustomException();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Other exception handling code.
        // ..
    }
}

public void OtherMethod()
{
    try
    {
        SendNotificaitonEmail();
    }
    catch(MyCustomException ex)
    {
        // Exception handling code.
        // ..
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Let's say I want to be sure that all of the operations, handled in the DAL code execute successfully.

I have methods like `UpdateUserData`, `GetUserById`, `ChangeUserPicture`.

So, if I want to check whether these operations have executed successfully, I should add some additional variables like:

```
bool UpdateUserData(User userToUpdate, out string errorMessage); 
User GetUserById(int id, out bool isError, out string errorMessage);
bool ChangeUserPicture(Picture picture, int id, out string errorMessage);
// ..
```

I have a simple app that uses all these methods:

```
string errorMessage;
bool isUserUpdatedSuccessfully = UpdateUserData(someUserToUpdate, out errorMessage); 

if (isUserUpdatedSuccessfully == true)
{
    // If the DAL operation was executed successfully, do something..
}
else
{
    // Code that informs the user that an error has occurred.
    MyCustomErrorLogger(errorMessage);        
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Treat exceptions as exceptions. Do not use them for normal program flow control.

Return values are for things that you expect are possible.

[The problem handling an exception locally and instead returning an error code is conceptually OK, but only if ALL consumers of that code check the error value, otherwise something bad has occurred and then is ignored.]

Comment: +1 It's as simple as that. No more, no less.

Comment: a lot of upvotes for an answer to a highly opinionated question

Comment: I don't think it is opinionated. It's best practice, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Okay, so If I want to check whether everything is okay in all of my methods, I should add similar variables to all of them?

bool UpdateUserData(User userToUpdate, out string errorMessage); User GetUserById(int id, out bool isError, out string errorMessage);

Comment: It is opinionated and off-topic, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The original answer is a general guideline which is correct but not very helpful because OP has a concrete problem. So the answer is correct but incomplete.

Comment: @MitchWheat Experience have nothing to do with being able to read a FAQ. It is neither a specific programming problem about code that does not work, software algorithm or about common tools. It's a simple "I have X and Y, which one do you think is better?", which is obviously opinionated. And we even have CR.SE for that. Anyway, it's on the verge of being closed.

Comment: When the consensus is of the same opinion, that's when it's called best practice.

Comment: @MitchWheat: The problem handling an exception locally and instead returning an error code is conceptually OK, but only if ALL consumers of that code check the error value, otherwise something bad has occurred and then is ignored.]

How can i do it properly otherwise? Please, give an example with similar code.